# Open up results from Find Results window in new tab/column

Tags: sublime-text-2

In Sublime Text 2 on Mac, I am using the two column layout. Is it possible to open results from the Find Results tab (when I search through a directory/multiple files) into the opposite tab.  For instance, if I have the search results in column one, I'd like to click on a result and have the file open in column two.  Is that a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>2</kbd> in order to move the file to 1st of 2nd column.